# Generate checkboxes and textboxes during loop (for next) in a module (runtime)

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to generate elements (checkboxes and textboxes) from a module to a userform in the number of the array elements which the array have. Example:

- **array4()**
- array4(1): "Peter Meier"
- array4(2): "Joe Garner"
- array4(3): "Phil Master"
- and so on
- **array2()**
- array2(1): 2
- array2(1): 2
- array2(2): 6
- array2(3): 160
- and so on

Both arrays have always the same number of arrays.

The Userform should show afterwoods:

1. Checkbox  /  Textfield.Text = Peter Meier  /   Textfield.Text = 2
2. Checkbox  /  Textfield.Text = Joe Garner    /  Textfield.Text = 6
3. and so on

and so on
Regards,
Yab86

Answer (score 0):

Might be more elegant to store both values in same array?

```vb
array(1,1) = "Peter Meier"
array(1,2) = "2"

array(2,1) = "Joe Garner"
array(2,2) = "2"
```

etc...

As for your problem, something like this maybe:

```vb
Sub Stuff()
    Dim vrData(2, 1) As Variant ' or vrData() and redim later
    Dim ctControl As Control
    Dim intPosX, intPosY As Integer
    Dim ufForm As BlankForm ' i.e. a blank userform you create first


    vrData(0, 0) = "Whatever"
    vrData(0, 1) = "3"
    vrData(1, 0) = "Something"
    vrData(1, 1) = "2"
    vrData(2, 0) = "Horse"
    vrData(2, 1) = "7"

    intPosX = 20
    intPosY = 20

    Set ufForm = New BlankForm

    For i = 0 To UBound(vrData, 1)
        Set ctControl = ufForm.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")
        With ctControl
            .Caption = vrData(i, 0)
            .Left = intPosX
            .Top = intPosY
        End With

        Set ctControl = ufForm.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With ctControl
            .Text = vrData(i, 1)
            .Left = intPosX + 100
            .Top = intPosY
        End With

        intPosY = intPosY + 20
    Next

    ufForm.Show
End Sub
```